# java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class

Tags: web-services, jsp, jakarta-ee, struts, axis

Below jsp displays the returned HashMap value from the webservice

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<%@page import="com.action.AuraDecisionWorsheetDetailsService"%>
<%@page import="com.action.AuraDecisionWorsheetDetailsServiceLocator"%>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="form1" method="post" action='gawd.jsp'>
<center><h1>DETAILS</h1></center>

<%
    try{
        AuraDecisionWorsheetDetailsService psi = new AuraDecisionWorsheetDetailsServiceLocator();

        com.action.AuraDecisionWorsheetDetails ps = psi.getAuraDecisionWorsheetDetails();

    if(request.getParameter("PolId")!=null){ 

        String pol_id=request.getParameter("PolId");


    %>
        <center><b>RESULT :</b> <%= ps.service(pol_id)%></center>
    <% }else
        {%>

    <TABLE align="center">
    <TR>
        <TD>ENTER POLICY NUMBER</TD>
        <TD><input type="text" name= "PolId"  /></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan="2" align="center">&nbsp;</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></TD>
    </TR>


    </TABLE>    
    <% } 
    }catch(Exception exe)
    {
        exe.printStackTrace();
    }
    %>

</form>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Received below exception

```
faultString: java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class com.solcorp.pathfinder.uidefs.UIElement in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@c87621

Caused by: java.io.IOException: No serializer found for class com.solcorp.pathfinder.uidefs.UIElement in registry org.apache.axis.encoding.TypeMappingDelegate@c87621
```

Web service takes one parameter i.e. pol_id and returns HashMap.
It is created using Apache Axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have so many problems in this code:

1. It is a bad practice to call webservices from the jsp, you should do it in the servlet. The jsp should mainly focus on presentation not on logic. Try using [jstl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html).
2. You are doing `alert(pol_id);` without opening any script tag. `alert` is a javascript function and must be contained inside `<script></script>`.
3. You have this line: `<TD><input type="text" name= "PolId"  %></TD>`, it should obviously be: `<input type="text" name= "PolId"  /></TD>` (note that i changed `%` at the end to `/`.
4. in this line: `<%= ps.service(pol_id)%>` you are missing `;` at the end.
5. You have this condition:

   ```
   `if(request.getParameter("PolId")!=null){ 
        String pol_id=request.getParameter("PolId")==null?"":request.getParameter("PolId");}`
   ```

   you are doing the same check twice, either remove the if or the ternary operator.

Fix these problems (the first one is really more of a best practice, so you can skip it for now), and then if you have more problems come back and post your question.

**EDIT:**
in your code you are eching the result from the service:

```
`<center><b>RESULT :</b> <%= ps.service(pol_id)%></center>`
```

but as you mentioned it is a Hashmap, so i don't think you can echo it directly. you need to echo the values you extract from it, so try doing this for testing:

```
//in the java snippet
Map map = ps.service(pol_id);
 ...
//in the html
<center><b>RESULT :</b> <%= map.get(0)%></center>
```

Comment: @flom2 I did all except 1 and 4,still getting the same exception.